# Hosting A Jar File On Amazon AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cron, executable-jar

I wrote a Java program and packaged it into an executable Jar file.

What I am looking for now, is to schedule this jar file to run daily using some sort of online Cron Job service.

I was considering using Amazon AWS. Can it achieve what I wanted? If yes, what service shall I use exactly and what are the steps I should proceed with? If not what are other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I currently am hosting a java project on an Amazon EC2 instance.  You can select the server instance you would like to use, e.g. Ubuntu, Windows Server, etc.  Once this is complete, you must configure your security settings so can connect to your EC2 instance and transfer your jar file to this server instance using scp or another file transfer service.  I have a repository in an Amazon S3 bucket, and it is very easy to transfer files from S3 to an EC2 instance via the "s3cmd" command (Note: I am using Ubuntu for my EC2 server instance).  Once the jar file is hosted on the server, all you need to do is create the cron job and it will run as scheduled as long as your EC2 instance is running.